# How do you set the scrollTop property of an element using refs with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a chat application with React, and I would like the scroll bar on my list of messages to start at the bottom as opposed to the top on page load so the user will see the most recent messages first.

I've set a ref on the component I want to access, and this seems to work properly. (The relevant lines are in the last three in `componentDidMount()`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import App from "./../App";
import styles from "./../styles/MessageList.css";
import Message from "./Message";

class MessageList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
      newMessageText: ""
    };
    // change to messages ref
    this.roomsRef = this.props.firebase.database().ref("rooms");
    this._input = React.createRef();    
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const dataSnapshot = this.props.firebase.database().ref("rooms");
    this.props.messagesRef.on("child_added", snapshot => {
      const message = snapshot.val();
      message.key = snapshot.key;
      this.setState({ messages: this.state.messages.concat(message) });
    });
    this.getActiveRoomMessages();    
    const messageBox = this._input.current;
    console.log(messageBox) // Logs DOM element correctly
    console.log(messageBox.scrollTop) // Logs correct property
    messageBox.scrollTop = messageBox.scrollHeight; // Does not change property 
  }

  // Other component methods
  getActiveRoomMessages() {
    if (this.props.activeRoom != null) {
      return this.state.messages
        .filter(message => message.roomId === this.props.activeRoom.key)
        .map(message => (
          <li>
            <span key={message.key}>
              <p className="sent-by">
                {message.username} SAYS:
            </p>
              <p className="message-text">
                {message.text}
              </p>
            </span>
            <div className="timestamp-and-delete-button">
              <p className="date-and-time-text">
                Sent @ {message.sentTime} on {message.sentDate}
              </p>
              <button
                onClick={() => { this.deleteMessage(message) }
                }
                className="delete-button">
                DELETE MESSAGE
          </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))
    }
  }

  deleteMessage = (messageToDelete) => {
    console.log(this.props.deletedRoom);
    const newMessagesArray = [];
    this.state.messages.map((message, i) => {
      if (message.key != messageToDelete.key) {
        newMessagesArray.push(message);
      }
    });
    this.setState({ messages: newMessagesArray });
    this.props.messagesRef.child(messageToDelete.key).remove();
  }

  getDeletedRoomMessages = (roomId) => {
    if (this.props.deletedRoom != null) {
      this.state.messages.map(message => {
        if (message.roomId === roomId) {
          this.deleteMessage(message);
        }
      })
      this.props.resetDeletedRoomState();
    };
  }

  //adding key values to each new message to be sent to database
  createMessage(newMessage) {
    let dateAndTime = new Date()
    this.props.messagesRef.push({
      text: this.state.newMessageText,
      roomId: this.props.activeRoom.key,
      username: this.props.currentUser ? this.props.currentUser : "Guest",
      sentDate: dateAndTime.toLocaleDateString(),
      sentTime: this.getTimeSent(dateAndTime)
    });
    this.setState({ newMessageText: "" })
  }

  getTimeSent(date) {
    let hour;
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let amPm;
    if (date.getHours() > 12) {
      hour = date.getHours() - 12;
      amPm = "PM"
    } else {
      hour = date.getHours();
      amPm = "AM"
    }
    return hour + ":" + minutes + " " + amPm;
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <React.Fragment>

        <div className="message-section-container">
          <div className="active-room">
            {this.props.activeRoom != null ? <h1 className="active-room-name">#{this.props.activeRoom.name} </h1>: "No room has been selected"}
          </div>
          <div className="list-of-messages"
               ref = {this._input}>
            <ul>
              {this.getActiveRoomMessages()}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="message-field">
            <form
              onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.createMessage(this.state.newMessageText);
              }}
            >
              <div className="message-text-field">
                <textarea
                  type="text"
                  id="message-field"
                  placeholder="Write a message"
                  cols="50"
                  rows="6"
                  value={this.state.newMessageText}
                  onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="message-field" />
                  <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="message-submit-button">
                    SUBMIT!
                  </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
};

export default MessageList;
```

The only piece of this that is not working at the moment is actually assigning a new value to the `scrollTop` property of the ref, which I'm trying to do with: `messageBox.scrollTop = messageBox.scrollHeight;`

I realize that this way of creating a ref is deprecated, but since the ref itself seems to be working, I don't think this would have any bearing on why I'm not able to reassign a property value on it.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: First, I don't see you assigning new value to your ref. Second, whats the expected behaviour, if you assign a new value to the scrollTop, i think it will jump.

Comment: I'm assigning a value to the ref with ` const messageBox = this._input.current;` and then giving the scrollTop property of the ref a new value with `messageBox.scrollTop = messageBox.scrollHeight;`... or at least that's what I'm intending to do with these lines.

Comment: it should work, try adding `console.log(this._input.current.scrollTop)` after `messageBox.scrollTop = messageBox.scrollHeight; // Does not change property` also try assigning directly `this._input.current.scrollTop=messageBox.scrollHeight`